# Shortcuts for combining multiples subfolders into one big folder?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I have a folder `DATA` which currently holds 6 subfolders.
I want to combine 5 of those subfolders together and then delete the empty subfolders (after combining).  Any one of those 5 could be
the main subfolder that holds the rest of the subfolders.

At this time, I would drag all subfolders into one main subfolder.
Go through each of the subfolders ctrl + A, cut, and then paste in the main subfolder and delete each empty folder.

Is there some sort of shortcut to this?

Comment: [How to Copy Files from Multiple Sub-Folders to a Single Folder? » Winhelponline](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/move-copy-files-multiple-sub-folders-single-folder/)

Answer (score 0):

In the explorer, go to the top folder of those subfolders, and search for `*`.

This will result in all files being shown. Simply Select them all and drag tehm into the target folder.